# Java BrowserLauncher throwing InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, exception

I'm using the BrowserLauncher2 library for opening the user's default web browser from my Swing app, but it's throwing a very confusing exception:

```
public static void openURL(String url) {
        try{
            BrowserLauncher launcher = new BrowserLauncher();
            launcher.openURLinBrowser(url);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

Exception:

edu.stanford.ejalbert.exception.BrowserLaunchingExecutionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at edu.stanford.ejalbert.launching.macos.MacOs3_1BrowserLaunching.openUrl(MacOs3_1BrowserLaunching.java:61)
    at edu.stanford.ejalbert.BrowserLauncherRunner.run(BrowserLauncherRunner.java:136)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:613)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at edu.stanford.ejalbert.launching.macos.MacOs3_1BrowserLaunching.openUrl(MacOs3_1BrowserLaunching.java:58)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission canOpenURLs)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:264)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:427)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
    at com.apple.eio.FileManager.openURL(FileManager.java:229)
    at com.apple.mrj.MRJPriv.openURL(MRJPriv.java:255)
    at com.apple.mrj.MRJFileUtils.openURL(MRJFileUtils.java:206)
    ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running your application with a `SecurityManager` set. Some code in the `AccessControlContext` (a.k.a. acc) does not have the required permission. Probably that code is your application code.

Answer (score 1):

An `InvocationTargetException` always wraps another exception which was caused while invoking a method or constructor via reflection. To solve your problem, you need to look at the exception under it, the `IllegalAccessException` which as Tom Hawtin points out, is being thrown because of the `SecurityManager`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `BrowserLauncher` does not support Mac OS < 10.2.

Also, on MacOS, `BrowserLauncher` launches the default browser, targeting a specific browser is not possible. You could try changing the default browser on your computer to see if that helps. Apparently this can be done by the following:
Start Safari -> Select Preferences -> in the General tab, find the Default web browser.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting AccessControlExceptions with BrowserLauncher2 via an applet of mine. Your situation may be similar, because you are running your app with a SecurityManager.

I solved my problem by signing the BrowserLauncher2 jar with my certificate. If your user accepts your certificate, BrowserLauncher should have the permissions it needs to do its job.